# Black screenshot taken with 'import' (ImageMagick)

Tags: linux, shell, imagemagick, gnome

I have a curious phenomenon.

I have a script which contains this line:

```
import -frame IMG_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).png
```

So, a screenshot of an area can be taken. Sometimes it appears that parts of the screenshot are black (see [sample image](http://2imgs.com/77780d27f4)):

[sample http://2imgs.com/2i/i/54c0fab6/e245ab35e0aa18c44354d04e40c908d5/77780d27f4.f.png](http://2imgs.com/2i/i/54c0fab6/e245ab35e0aa18c44354d04e40c908d5/77780d27f4.f.png)

Does anyone have an idea why this behavior occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a correct answer. You have to test it...

I myself have no personal experience in using `import` for screenshooting X11 screens.

My suspicion is that the black area comes from *transparent* sections in the X11 window. So you need to pick or enforce an output format that supports transparency (or alpha channel). That's where my suggestion comes from:

```
import -frame PNG32:IMG_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).png
```

The `PNG32:` prefix to the file name should be forcing 32-bit PNG (which includes as a fourth channel the alpha channel.